# Using htaccess to drop ?tag= from the end of all URLs

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

This is my last task with my ecommerce website and I now need to drop `?tag=shirts`, `?tag=hoodies` and `?tag=tanks` from all URLs using htaccess. The url works perfectly with or without the ?tag at the end so its just a matter of cosmetics and consistency across the site. I cannot just drop "shirts", "hoodies" and "tanks" from any URL because my categories are domain.com/shirts/", "domain.com/hoodies/" and domain.com/tanks/" so it has to explicitly contain the "tag=" prefix in the condition.

For example:

```
https://www.domain.com/animals/awesomeproduct32/?tag=shirts
https://www.domain.com/animals/awesomeproduct5/?tag=hoodies
https://www.domain.com/animals/awesomeproduct3/?tag=tanks
```

I want the ?tag part dropped off in ALL circumstances (and remember, that this will not create any 404's so it's totally fine):

```
https://www.domain.com/animals/awesomeproduct32/
https://www.domain.com/animals/awesomeproduct5/
https://www.domain.com/animals/awesomeproduct3/
```

Please note that the category name (in this case, its "animals") and the product name is variable.

Here is my htacess file (big thanks to @anubhava for all his help with this):

```
# remove /design/ from URLs and redirect
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+design/(\S*)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

# internally add design/ to know set of URIs
RewriteRule ^(skulls-bones|characters|abstract|animals|games|geek-nerd|graphic|keep-calm|movies-tv|pop-culture|tattoo|typography)(/.*)?$ design/$1$2 [L,NC]

# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+product/search/\?tag=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/? [R=301,L,NE]

# internal forward from pretty URL to actual one
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/design/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ product/search/?tag=$1 [L,QSA]
```

My only concern is making sure that this dropping of the ?tag doesn't interfere with my other rules.

Thanks!

Comment: `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^tag= [NC]` followed by `RewriteRule .* $0? [L]`. You can add `QSD` flag after `L` if your Apache is 2.4 or later.

Comment: Ok slight adjustment, my htaccess rules redirect "/index.php?route=product/search&tag=shirts" to "/shirts/, etc. so that rule kills that. However, i think it would work if you could make exclusions for the following - http://pastebin.com/LPdKUW9d - everything else it must drop the tag part.